# Integration project automation and test strategy

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-strategy, test-planning

I recently joined a company and will be working on an integration project. The Dev team will be building a solution to replace Excel spreadsheets. Data from multiple spreadsheets will now be displayed in a 3rd party Web product. So instead of Excel reading data from databases we  will call the 3rd party Rest APIs.

I've done automation with Specflow of internal applications but never integration. I will appreciate if someone with expertise give me ideas of a test plan/strategy. What types of tests should be included?

First thoughts, I assume the Dev team will build some sort of internal API that I can use in building a new framework.

So would I just need tests to validate the new API is fetching the same and correct data as the spreadsheets. Then add UI automation to check the data fetched is correctly displayed in the UI?

One requirement is when the underlying database changes then the UI should refresh within 30 secs. How can I test this?